# how to solve this continuous random variable problem?

Tags: statistics, random-variables, uniform-distribution, exponential-distribution

A student has two calculators – an old and a new one. The time it takes the old calculator to provide an answer to a difficult integration problem is exponentially distributed with mean 8 seconds. The new one gives the answer uniformly between 2 seconds and 6 seconds. If the integration was computed within 4 seconds, what is the probability that the student used the old calculator?

Comment: Did you try anything to solve this problem?

Comment: Any thoughts?  What prior distribution did you have in mind?  What is the probability that the old calculator got the job done in $≤4$ seconds? What about the new one?

Comment: Well, the probability that the old calculator got the job done in 4 seconds is pretty easy, it is just P(X<4)~X follows exponential distribution. What I don't know is how does the new calculator comes into place into solving the question.

Comment: So...what is the probability that the old calculator got the job done in $≤4$ seconds?  The answer should be a number.  For the new calculator, the computation is much easier.  Once you have both of these you can use Bayes' methodology to solve the problem.  You'll have to have a prior which I suppose will be $\frac 12$ for each?

Comment: By bayes methodology you mean probability that the old calculator is used given that the job is done in < 4 seconds or P(old calculator|X<4)?

Comment: @lulu Thanks for confirming my doubts...I knew there was some missing information here (i.e. the prior distribution).

Comment: @Exsanguinator   Same thing, more or less.   Using your prior probabilities (whatever they may be), you compute the probability that the computation gets done in less than $4$ seconds.  Then the answer you want is that portion which is explained by the old calculator.  As the old calculator is slower, you expect the new estimate of the probability to be lower than the prior (unless your prior was $0$).

Comment: Also, in solving P(x<4), we could just use the equation 1-e^(-lambda*x), am i right? lambda = 1/8 per second since you can solve a problem in 8 seconds, it follows that you can solve an eight of a problem in a second. Anyway, P(x<4)=0.3935

Comment: @Math1000  Usually in these problems the writer expects you to assume a uniform prior...but that's a lazy habit.  Here, say, I'd be content to assume uniformity if you said one calculator was black and the other silver.  But slow vs fast?  Surely the kid would gravitate toward the fast one.  Else why'd she go buy a new one in the first place?

Comment: @Exsanguinator  I agree with that value (and with your reasoning).  What about the new calculator.

Comment: @lulu I suppose for the new calculator, since it is uniformly distributed from 2 to 6 seconds, P(x<4) would be (4-2)/(6-2) = 0.5.

Comment: @Exsanguinator  Great.  So, sticking with the uniform prior...before the kid ran the computation, we would have computed that the probability that it got done in less than $4$ seconds was $\frac 12\times .3935+\frac 12\times .5 \sim .4467$.  Can you conclude from here?

Comment: @lulu I just left the prior as a parameter, the computations are the same...

Comment: @Math1000  Sure.  I have to guess that they meant uniform, though.  But in practice, of course, you get lots of observed data and you have to iterate Bayes', so it's good to have the general formula.

Comment: @lulu So we assume that the kid using each calculator has equal probabilities (=0.5)?

Comment: @lulu Thank you so much for your help! I finally got it. I have been scratching my head for the past few hours for a problem that I did not expect to be a very simple one.

Comment: Also thanks to @Math1000

Comment: @Exsanguinator  Well, that's the prior probability I kept asking you about.  You didn't say what it was so I guessed you meant uniform.  You can use the posted solution below to play with different priors.  To be clear:  this has to be an "external input".  That is, it isn;t determined by the problem.   If your prior was that the kid only uses the new one, then you will surely stick with that.

Comment: @Exsanguinator  No problem.  Glad to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $T$ be the time it took to answer the question, $E$ the event "old calculator was used," and $f_T$, $f_{T\mid E}$, $f_{T\mid E^c}$ the probability densitity of $T$, the conditional density of $T$ given $E$, and the conditional density of $T$ given $E^c$. Assume the prior probability that the old calculator was used is $p:=P(E)\in(0,1)$. Using Bayes' rule, we have
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(E\mid T\leqslant 4) &= \frac{\mathbb P(T\leqslant 4\mid E)\mathbb P(E)}{\mathbb P(T\leqslant 4\mid E)\mathbb P(E) + \mathbb P(T\leqslant 4\mid E^c)\mathbb P(E^c)}\\
&= \frac{\mathbb P(T\leqslant 4\mid E)p}{\mathbb P(T\leqslant 4\mid E)p + \mathbb P(T\leqslant 4\mid E^c)(1-p)}.
\end{align}
Now,
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(T\leqslant 4\mid E) &= \int_{(-\infty,4]} f_{T\mid E}\\
&= \int_0^4 \frac18 e^{-\frac18 t}\,\mathsf dt\\
&= 1-e^{-\frac12}
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(T\leqslant 4\mid E^c) &= \int_{(-\infty,4]}f_{T\mid E^c}\\
&= \int_2^4 \frac14\,\mathsf dt\\
&=\frac12,
\end{align}
so it follows that
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(E\mid T\leqslant 4) &= \frac{p\left(1-e^{-\frac12}\right)}{p\left(1-e^{-\frac12}\right) + \frac12(1-p)}.
\end{align}

Comment: excuse me, but what does the variable E^c denote?

Comment: I see, it is the complement of E, which means that it is the probability that the kid used the new calculator, am i right?

Comment: The complement of $E$. An event $E$ is a (measurable) subset of the sample space $\Omega$, so $$E^c = \{\omega\in\Omega: \omega\notin E\}. $$